# How do I place 2-3 digit numbers obtained from a file into an array?

Tags: c, arrays

```
main ()
{
        FILE *pRead;
        FILE *pWrite;
        char lastname [20];
        char firstname [20];
        char grade [4];
        char gradefi [4];
        char gradeltr [3];
        int i=0;

        pRead=fopen ("testtext.dat", "r");

        if (pRead == NULL || pWrite == NULL)
                printf ("\nFile cannot be opened\n");
        else
                printf ("\nContents of testtext.dat\n\n");
                fscanf (pRead, "%[^,]%[^\n]%s", lastname, firstname, &grade);
                printf ("\n");
                pWrite=fopen ("report.txt", "w");
                fprintf (pWrite, "%s %s %s\n", firstname, lastname, &grade);
        while (!feof(pRead))
                {
                        ++i;
                        printf ("%s %s %s\n", firstname, lastname, &grade);
                        fscanf(pRead, "%[^,]%[^\n]%s", lastname, firstname, &grade);
                        fprintf (pWrite, "%s %s %s\n", firstname, lastname, &grade);
                }

fclose(pRead);
fclose(pWrite);

printf ("\nThere are %d student(s) in this list\n", i);
```

Comment: How's the file formatted? Can you elaborate on where you're running into trouble?

Comment: What does `%[^,]` in `fscanf` format mean? You're missing an `s` in the format.  Also, why `&grade` and not just `grade`?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?  There are a number of problems with this code, but I'm not sure exactly what you want us to tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not to look like an old stale paranoid fart or anything, but I suggest you put some curly brackets around the consequent statments after `else` and see what happens.